# Is it Smart to buy a carbon mountainbike?

Tags: mountain-bike

I'm planning in buying a mountainbike but i'm not sure wether to buy a carbon or an aluminium one. My main concern is that when i fall, will the carbon frame break faster or become unusable significantly quicker than the aluminium one?
It's either the Ghost htx 5 lc or the Thompson xc650 ALU.

Comment: Have a look at this question - the answers may help you. 
http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1328/carbon-fibre-mountain-bikes